# CDI: Disable event firing and observers during unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, cdi, jboss-arquillian

In a project I have @SessionScoped bean called "OrganizationManager" which fires an event when a certain field changes its value:

```
event.fire(new OrganizationChangedEvent());
```

A method called "reloadOnOrganizationChange" of another bean observes the event and does something like this

```
public void reloadOnOrganizationChange(@Observes OrganizationChangedEvent organizationChangedEvent){
 ...    
}
```

All works as expected.

But during unit testing I do not want event firing/observing to happen as I want to test aspects not related to the Event/Observer mechanism and the events create unwanted dependencies on observing classes. In my case I'm relying on Arquillian in my unit/integration tests.

What is the best way to do this? Can I disable events for testing?

Comment: Hmm. You could remove the class containing the reload method from the Arquillian setup. Then there is no observer anymore. In fact, having too much classes in the setup step looks more like an integration test.

Comment: You might want to add some code from your test-class to your question.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Thank you - you are probably right. I just discovered that by adding whole packages, I added the classes to the deployment in a non-granular way. Will try it out..